# Use different template for my contact us form in shopware5

Tags: shopware

I need to use a different design template for my Shopware5 contact us page.

Currently this form is loaded from the “Form” controller and view is “frontend/form/index.tpl” if I can create a custom template under “frontend/form/” directory I can solve this issue.

My question is how can I tell my controller to use new template when the url or some id is “contact-us2” or something for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to do so.

**1. Switch in the view:**

You would be able to get the Url segment in the view. So, a very dirty way: Just decide which sub template will be included in Smarty depending on the given Url. But as I already told, this is not the way you should ever do! Even though it's a way...

**2. Switch via event subscriber:**

Just create a Shopware plugin, listen to the Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend_Form event. Then check whatever is necessary to decide which view should be loaded - maybe the current Shops locale or whatever. Just do

```
$this->View()->loadTemplate('frontend/path/to/your/file.tpl');
```

and the controller should load the template you specified.

Kind regards